# Selenium find element by class name returning wrong info

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to run this in Python

```
driver.get("myWebite")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('artist-name')

print(element)
```

and the answer I was expecting was 'Bowie' but what it returned is

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="23123aef156e1f8c358126ba5b6e2974", element="16198427-753f-4293-b9ee-df1826309113")>
```

Comment: Please Share the HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get("myWebite")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('artist-name')

print(element.text)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!